# Decode audio buffer in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using an express server to convert text to speech using aws polly. I can send back the response data as an array of ints and get it to play with the flutter audioplayers package by converting it to Uint8List like the following.

```
final res = await post('url',
  headers: {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json'},
  body: body,
);
final decoded = json.decode(res.body);
return Uint8List.fromList(decoded['AudioStream']['data'].cast<int>());
```

My problem is I want to send the audio stream buffer instead of the array of integers but I am struggling to decode it in dart. This is how I am sending the audio from the server I'm just unsure how I can convert it to Uint8List in the flutter app.

```
const data =  await Polly.synthesizeSpeech(input).promise()
res.set('Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg')
res.send(data.AudioStream)
```

Edit: When testing in postman I can play the audio from the response. I updated the way I am sending the data from express to the following

```
res.send(Buffer.from(data.AudioStream, 'base64'))
```

but decoding the response in dart like this throws a FormatException, maybe I am doing this part wrong

```
Uint8List decoded = Base64Codec().decode(res.body);
```

exception

```
FormatException: Invalid character (at character 4)
```

Comment: Not sure, what about using `decode()` from [convert package](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.3/dart-convert/Base64Codec/decode.html) which returns a Uint8List from a string?

Comment: yeah I tried but it throws an exception. I updated the question and the way I am sending the data from express but it still throws an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was decoding the data the wrong way in dart, doing the following returns a Uint8List from the response.

```
return res.bodyBytes
```